# How to know whether data file for an external table is increasing

Tags: oracle, plsql, external-tables

I have a PLSQL application, the application has a oracle job (ABC.AUDIT_LOG_IMPORT_JOB) that is runs for every 10 min and picks the file from the log pool and process it using a oracle procedure (ABC.PR_IMPORT_AUDIT_LOG).

Sometimes very large files (4 to 6 GB) are imported in the log pool, when oracle job(ABC.AUDIT_LOG_IMPORT_JOB) is successfully executed the procedure takes some time to process these files. The procedure uses some external tables.

When the procedure is started then some external table is called to read the data from the file. Since the file is large it takes some time to import these files while the procedure is already started which causes the following error.

```
KUP-05011: Size of file inProgress.txt in directory /opt/app/logpool/auditlog/ has changed from 3630039040 to 3852599296.
```

How to solve this problem?

oracle job is as shown below

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => 'ABC.AUDIT_LOG_IMPORT_JOB',
            job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
            job_action => 'ABC.PR_IMPORT_AUDIT_LOG',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => NULL,
            repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=10',
            end_date => NULL,
            enabled => FALSE,
            auto_drop => FALSE,
            comments => '');

         
     
 
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => 'ABC.AUDIT_LOG_IMPORT_JOB', 
             attribute => 'store_output', value => TRUE);
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => 'ABC.AUDIT_LOG_IMPORT_JOB', 
             attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);
      
   
  
    
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
             name => 'ABC.AUDIT_LOG_IMPORT_JOB');
END;
```

the procedure that uses this external table is as shown below

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Procedure PR_IMPORT_AUDIT_LOG
--------------------------------------------------------
set define off;

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "ABC"."PR_IMPORT_AUDIT_LOG" 
  AS

   CURSOR CUR_FILE_LIST
   IS SELECT FNAME
      FROM EXT_TAB_IMPORT_FILE_LIST 
      WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(FNAME,'AL_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{8}_\d{6}.txt');

   

   V_INSERT_TIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    -- This is to prevent the logs from being created in other than English
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = ''AMERICAN''';

   
    
    FOR REC_FILE_LIST IN CUR_FILE_LIST
    LOOP
      -- Copy the original file to the AL_IMPORTBAD directory
    UTL_FILE.FCOPY('ABC_AUDITLOG', FNAME, 'ABC_AL_IMPORTBAD', FNAME||'-Original_file');

      --RENAME FILE IN inProgress.txt
      UTL_FILE.FRENAME('ABC_AUDITLOG', REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME, 'ABC_AUDITLOG', 'inProgress.txt', TRUE);  
      
      IF PR_AL_IMPORT_CHECK_CORIAID (REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME) --If there are any errors, then there are no records with correct records are saved in the AL_IMPORT folder.
      THEN
      
         --Insert into audit_log
         PR_INSERT_AUDIT_LOG_FROM_FILE(V_INSERT_TIMESTAMP);--Records are inserted from file with correct coridid and during insert just oracle regexp are checked.
         --Check log file
         PR_CHECK_AUDIT_LOG_FILE(REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME);
         --ERROR HANDLING
         PR_IMPORT_CHECK_LOG_FILES( REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME
                                  , V_INSERT_TIMESTAMP);

         --move inProgress into archive and rename it with the old name
         UTL_FILE.FRENAME('ABC_AUDITLOG', 'inProgress.txt', 'ABC_AL_IMPORTLOG', REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME, TRUE);
         
      ELSE
         --move inProgress into archive and rename it with the old name
--          UTL_FILE.FRENAME('ABC_AUDITLOG', 'inProgress.txt', 'ABC_AL_IMPORTBAD', REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME, TRUE);
      END IF;     
      
      --remove inProgress.bad
      BEGIN
         UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('ABC_AUDITLOG','inProgress.bad');
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            IF SQLCODE = -29283 -- suppresses no file found exception
            THEN
               NULL;
            ELSE
               RAISE;
            END IF;
      END;         
      --remove inProgress.log      
      BEGIN
         UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('ABC_AUDITLOG','inProgress.log');
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            IF SQLCODE = -29283 -- suppresses no file found exception
            THEN
               NULL;
            ELSE
               RAISE;
            END IF;
      END;

       --remove inProgress.txt
      BEGIN
         UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('ABC_AUDITLOG','inProgress.txt');
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            IF SQLCODE = -29283 -- suppresses no file found exception
            THEN
               NULL;
            ELSE
               RAISE;
            END IF;
      END;
      
      COMMIT;
      
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DECLARE
         V_PROCEDURE_NAME  VARCHAR2(30)  := $$PLSQL_UNIT;
         V_SUBJECT         VARCHAR2(255) := 'Error on DB procedure '||V_PROCEDURE_NAME||' on '||to_char(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
         V_BODY            VARCHAR2(10000) := 'Hi all,'||chr(10)||chr(10)||'Procedure '||V_PROCEDURE_NAME||' returned the following error:'||chr(10)||SQLERRM;
      BEGIN
         SEND_MAIL ( 'GENERIC_DB_ERROR', V_SUBJECT,V_BODY);
         RAISE;
      END;      
END;

/
```

the external table that reads the records from the file is as follows

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Procedure PR_INSERT_AUDIT_LOG_FROM_FILE
--------------------------------------------------------
set define off;

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "ABC"."PR_INSERT_AUDIT_LOG_FROM_FILE" (P_IMPORT_TIMESTAMP IN TIMESTAMP)
AS 
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO AUDIT_LOG 
      ( ID                   
      , PRIMARY_NAME   
      , PRIMARY_VALUE  
      , TERMINAL_DATE
      , LAND_ID           
      )
   SELECT ID                   
        , TRIM(PRIMARY_NAME)
        , TRIM(PRIMARY_VALUE)
        , TERMINAL_DATE        
        , LAND_ID                        
        , P_IMPORT_TIMESTAMP
   FROM EXT_TAB_AUDIT_LOG AL
   LEFT OUTER JOIN VERFIY_NAME VWZ ON VWZ.VERFIY_TABLE_ID = TRIM(AL.VERFIY_TABLE_ID)
   WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (ID,'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
   AND   PRIMARY_NAME IS NOT NULL
   AND   PRIMARY_VALUE IS NOT NULL
   AND   TERMINAL_DATE IS NOT NULL
   AND   LAND_ID IS NOT NULL
 


   COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DECLARE
         V_PROCEDURE_NAME  VARCHAR2(30)  := $$PLSQL_UNIT;
         V_SUBJECT         VARCHAR2(255) := 'Error on DB procedure '||V_PROCEDURE_NAME||' on '||to_char(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
         V_BODY            VARCHAR2(10000) := 'Hi all,'||chr(10)||chr(10)||'Procedure '||V_PROCEDURE_NAME||' returned the following error:'||chr(10)||SQLERRM;
      BEGIN
         SEND_MAIL ( 'GENERIC_DB_ERROR', V_SUBJECT,V_BODY);
         RAISE;
      END;  
END PR_INSERT_AUDIT_LOG_FROM_FILE;

/
```

Answer (score 0):

In My Humble Opinion and having used Oracle-SQL*Loader Frequently with Limited Memory Desktop-Hosts;

You can PreProcess big or small files as equal size chunks based on Lines or Bytes,

Using Shell Script and Embedding PLSQL/SQL*LOADER inside those scripts.